# IntellIj 2022.2 java.lang.AssertionError when refresh gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

When I refresh gradle project, I have an error in the console and I used Java 11 and gradle 7.4.2.
I tried several things but none of them worked.

- Upgrading IDE version to 2022.2.
- Deleting gradle caches
- Deleting .gradle folder and redownloaded again.

I am able to build project using cmd but I am having issues loading project in Intellij.
Can someone please help?

Exception during working with external system: java.lang.AssertionError
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.CommonGradleProjectResolverExtension.createModule(CommonGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:126)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.gradleJava.configuration.kpm.KotlinKPMGradleProjectResolver.createModule(KotlinKPMGradleProjectResolver.kt:56)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.gradleJava.configuration.KotlinMPPGradleProjectResolver.createModule(KotlinMPPGradleProjectResolver.kt:76)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.gradleJava.configuration.KotlinGradleProjectResolverExtension.createModule(KotlinGradleProjectResolverExtension.kt:188)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.createModule(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.TracedProjectResolverExtension.createModule(TracedProjectResolverExtension.java:37)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.convertData(GradleProjectResolver.java:398)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:317)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:789)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:771)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.lambda$execute$0(GradleExecutionHelper.java:132)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.maybeFixSystemProperties(GradleExecutionHelper.java:158)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.lambda$execute$1(GradleExecutionHelper.java:132)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleConnectorService$Companion.withGradleConnection(GradleConnectorService.kt:181)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.GradleConnectorService.withGradleConnection(GradleConnectorService.kt)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:128)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:151)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:71)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:43)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:36)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:48)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:115)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:151)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:135)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.executeImpl(ExternalSystemUtil.java:491)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.lambda$execute$0(ExternalSystemUtil.java:327)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceHeavyActivities.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceHeavyActivities.java:21)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceImpl.java:187)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:327)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:614)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.startTask(CoreProgressManager.java:442)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.startTask(ProgressManagerImpl.java:114)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsynchronously$5(CoreProgressManager.java:493)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:252)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:188)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:608)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:683)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:639)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:607)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:175)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:252)

Comment: With the latest IDE version try to re-import the project from scratch: delete `.idea` directory and open project via File | New | Project from existing sources. If the problem remains, report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample project to reproduce.